# 'how we make a car' or 'how do we make a car'?

Tags: grammar, differences

I don't know the difference between *how we make a car* and *how do we make a car*.

I searched on the internet; there are examples for both but I do not understand in which cases they would each be used.

Comment: That question would be better suited for the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: In addition to the fact that, as @AlexW says, this is the wrong site, you'll also need to provide some more context. Did you see these sentences somewhere? Do you want to use them in a particular context and not know which to use?

Comment: I favour leaving this question here, as I'm not certain we have something similar in ELU. An ELL question is at [“Do in WH- questions”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20615/question-about-use-of-do-in-wh-questions/20619#20619) and its linked duplicate.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608581/2085).

Answer (score 7):

1. *How we make a car* is not a sentence; it's a subordinate clause. It's certainly not a question.
2. *How do we make a car* **is** a sentence, and a question (if it has question intonation, i.e. **?**)

Both of them come from the structure

- *We make a car `Indef_manner`*

where `Indef_manner` means some indefinite manner or way (of making a car).
`Indef_manner` is what gets turned into *how*, the interrogative pronoun for expressions of
manner and means, just as *when* is the relative/interrogative pronoun for expressions of time.

The difference between the two examples that come from this structure is that
   the first sentence has a pronoun in front, **but** no other change, while
   the second sentence has a pronoun in front, **and** an auxiliary verb before the subject.

Putting the verb before the subject is the mark of a question. So the second one is a question.
The first one is an Embedded Question, or Free Relative, which is a type of [complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Complements.pdf).
Embedded questions do not invert auxiliary verbs with the subject.

- ***How can they make this car so ugly?***
  (full sentence; question; auxiliary verb *can* precedes subject *they*)
- *I don't know **how they can make this car so ugly***.
  (embedded question object complement of *know*; subject *they* precedes  auxiliary verb *can*)

Comment: Or could be a clumsy exclamative sentence!

Answer (score 4):

When an interrogative pronoun is the subject of a sentence, *do* is not required. As interrogative pronouns normally need to be at the start of the sentence, subject–verb inversion doesn’t happen either.

> He makes the car. *(Statement; “he” is the subject)*
>   Who makes the car? *(Question: “who” is the subject)*

When the question does not have an interrogative pronoun as the subject, *do* or another modal verb is required. That verb precedes its subject.

> How do we make the car? *(“We” is the subject and “how” is an interrogative adverb)*